# Object privileges in Oracle Data Modeler

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I couldn't find a declarative way to store typical privs like `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE` in table definition (in Relational Model) of Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 19.2. I can places SQL `GRANT` into Table Properties -> Scripts -> After Create, but prefer more suitable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do it in the Relational Model, you do it in a physical model - to a specific kind of database, in this case, a 12c Release 2 database.

It's at the physical level that you start to worry about things like storage properties, encryption, compression, partitions, and security (grants).

[image]